# Manage Subdomain Zone with AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a domain `example.tld` that is registered with one company and hosted with another. That website uses https and has a let's encrypt certificate setup by the hosting company through an automated script. I'm trying to an s3 bucket accessible from `sub.example.tld`.

I currently have a public s3 bucket and a CNAME setup with my hosting company to point `sub` to my bucket. I'm able to access the contents of my bucket from the http and https protocols using an Amazon generated domain, and from http only from `sub.example.tld`.

I know I can setup s3 with cloudflare and and use a cname with https there, however, since my domain name isn't hosted with aws I have to upload import a certificate which I do not have.

What I'm thinking of how I can proceed is to create a hosted zone in route 53 for `sub.example.tld`. Then I can delete the current CNAME registration with my hosting company to the bucket and instead create some kind of DNS record with my hosting company to point `sub` to the hosted zone with Amazon.

I'm able to create the following DNS records: A, CNAME, MX, NS, TXT, SRV, AAAA, DNAME, and CAA.

Does my idea of creating a hosted zone for the subdomain make sense? And if so, what type of DNS record would I create with my host to allow me to have a subdomain managed elsewhere?

Comment: If you want to delegate subdomain authority to another nameserver(s), you need NS record(s) for the subdomain: `sub.example.tld  NS  some.other.nameserver.example.com`, but that by itself will not solve anything related to hosting https static website in s3 bucket. Perhaps take a look at docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html, the part about https

Comment: I think AWS is able to generate the certificate automatically if the zone is hosted with them. When I create a hosted zone in AWS it creates a NS record with four paths: ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.co.uk., ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.net., ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.org., and ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.com.. Would I create four NS records on my current host? One to each of these paths? Or would I randomly select one? It also gives me two SOA paths: ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.co.uk. and awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. I imagine I would leave those alone?

Comment: You can create one NS record in your parent zone, and later when everything is setup correctly add other three (for higher availability)